# Including jQuery and other JS files in Liferay Theme

Tags: jquery, liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme

I use Liferay 6.1 and I created my theme (`sample-theme`) and I want add `jQuery`.
How can I do that?

Why I have folders: `sample-theme` and `liferay-work` and both have folders: css, js, templates?

I created folder `_diffs` and subfolder `js` and there copy jQuery and add in `portal_normal.vm`:

```
<script src="/html/js/jquery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
```

And I don't see any changes, Why? How can I add jQuery? Not only to a single portlet but for all.

---

I don't have folder **docroot** I am use Maven and in **src/main/webapp** I created folder **_diffs** and inside folder **js**, there I add **jquery.js** and in **_diffs** created templates folder an d paste:

```
<script src="$javascript_folder/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
```

And still it is wrong. Maybe folder _diffs should be in another places? What should be a structure of maven project?

Comment: For building using maven this might help you: http://www.liferaysolution.com/2012/09/maven-build-with-liferay.html

Answer (score 8):

You can add all your javascript files to the `js` folder in your theme like:

> sample-theme/docroot/_diffs/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js

And then to make it available for everybody you can write any of the following lines in the `<head>` section of the template files `portal_normal.vm` and `portal_pop_up.vm` present in the directory `sample-theme/docroot/_diffs/templates/`:

```
#js ("$javascript_folder/jquery-1.8.2.min.js")
```

Or

```
<script src="$javascript_folder/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
```

<sub>Note: `portal_pop_up.vm` is for applying your javascript changes to AUI dialog pop-ups, if you are using them</sub>

#### Some more explanation as to how things work:

`$javascript_folder` is a velocity variable present in the theme's template files which points to the javascript storage path (default is: `${root-path}/js`) which can be defined in the `liferay-look-and-feel.xml` like this:

```
<theme id="sample" name="Sample">
    <root-path>/html</root-path> <!-- optional -->
    <javascript-path>${root-path}/js/jQuery</javascript-path> <!-- So path becomes: sample-theme/html/js/jQuery -->
</theme>
```

You can also customize `${root-path}` just like `<javascript-path>` by specifying it in `liferay-look-and-feel.xml` as `<root-path>` as shown. The default value of `${root-path}` is `/` i.e. it refers to the directory `sample-theme/`.

Basically the folders `css`, `js`, `templates` & `images` are the ones which gets updated  with the changes you make in the corresponding `_diffs` folder (`_diffs/css`, `_diffs/js` etc) when you build the theme. So that is the reason the velocity variables like `$javascript_folder` & `$css_folder` point to `sample-theme/js` & `sample-theme/css` respectively instead of `sample-theme/_diffs/js` or `sample-theme/_diffs/css`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Add

`<script src="$themeDisplay.getPathThemeRoot()js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript">` in portal_normal.vm

after adding the file to sample-theme/docroot/_diff/js folder
 
You can also use a CDN directly 

`<script src="<jquery url in CDN>" type="text/javascript">`

Answer (score 1):

You should add **jquery-1.8.2.min.js** to the folder **docroot/_diffs/js** in your theme. Then in **docroot/_diffs/templates/portal_normal.vm** you should add the following line to the <head /> section:

```
<script src="$javascript_folder/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
```

I think, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

This should be helpful for you

```
 <script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" ></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. diffs is only required when there is ant project, for MAVEN you do not need diffs
2. request.getContextPath is useful when u want to do it in portlets & Not themes.
3. you can use "$javascript_folder to access anything inside js folder