# How to include js file to Velocity template?

Tags: javascript, liferay, velocity

I am new to velocity.

I want to create new Liferay theme using bootstrap. But don't know how to include `js` files in the template.

Comment: You might find this [detailed answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12951958/468763) to a similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12936061/468763), very useful.

Comment: It might be a duplicate of the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12936061/1734150) mentioned in the above comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it's the same way as you would with an HTML page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/my-theme/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Just make sure that the JavaScript is in the relevant js folder in the theme's folder structure.

Comment: You mean that path to js file no need in any velocity variables? Just write it begin theme root?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't need to be. However if you're using across multiple templates for some reason then you might want to set in a Velocity variable.